# what is the difference of using data and attr to set some value from jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I am trying to add data-id attribute in the table column. So, I can add like these two ways.

```
$(this).data('id',10);
```

And,

```
$(this).attr('data-id',10);
```

What is the exact difference of these two methods. And which one is better to use in jQuery.

Comment: `data()` reads from jQuery's in-memory cache (and is therefore faster once that object has been created) while `attr()` reads from the DOM. See the duplicate for more information

Comment: read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr

Comment: Probably in the dup:`.data()` will apply type coercion while `.attr()` will always be a string.  `<div data-id="10"/>` `$(this).data('id') === 10` `$(this).attr('data-id') === "10";`